# Heat Equation problem 001

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}=k\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial x^2}$ and $V=V_0sin(nt)$ for $x=0$ and $V=0$ when $x$ is a very large number, what's the solution of the equation? Here none of the standard solution of the heat Equation is working,cause the time is given in a periodic function,in the solutions time is always in exponential form like $e^(-c^2p^2t)$,that's where I'm stuck

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I haven't really checked if it's going to work, but you could perhaps try looking for a solution of the form $V(x,t) = f(x) \sin(nt) + g(x) \cos(nt)$, where $f(0)=V_0$ and $g(0)=0$.

Comment: So after using this equation I put the values in the given differential equation and got a pair of simultaneous equation,after solving that and putting the values i got the right answer,can you tell how you guessed the equation will be of the form V(x,t)=f(x)sin(nt)+g(x)cos(nt),